# Laravel 5.2 Validator for text and multiple files

Tags: php, file, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I've been having some trouble validating multiple files and text at same time.
when I validate the whole request `$request->all();` the file rules wont work. 
`'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,gif|max:3000'`.
That gets fixed if I only validate the files in an array `array('file'=> $file)`, but this way I cant validate the other inputs.

I got the multiple files part from the internet, and added my part for the other inputs, here's my function:

```
 public function createNewPost(Request $request) {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->status= "borrador";
        $post->save();
        $post->img = "/uploads/posts/".$post->id;
        $post->save();

        $files = Input::file('file');
        $file_count = count($files);
        $uploadcount = 0;
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $rules = array(
            'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,gif|max:3000',
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required'
            );
            $messages = [
                'title.required' => 'Sin titulo?',
                'body.required' =>  'No has escrito nada',
                'file.required' => 'Selecciona al menos 1 imagen.',
                'file.mimes' => 'No puedes utilizar ese tipo de imagen, intenta con (jpg/png/jpeg).',
                'file.max' => 'El total de imagenes no puede pesar mas de 3MB.'
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules, $messages);
            if($validator->passes()){
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/posts/'.$post->id;
                //$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = $uploadcount.".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $uploadcount ++;
            }
        }
        if($uploadcount == $file_count){
            Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
            return Redirect::to('/admin/post/new');
        } 
        else {
          return Redirect::to('/admin/post/new')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and remove your foreach files loop:

```
$files = count($this->input('file')) - 1;
foreach(range(0, $files) as $index) {
    $rules['file.' . $index] = 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,gif|max:3000';
}
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-validating-multiple-file-input?page=1)